# Python dev has no installation Candidate while installing mitmf

Tags: python

Hey guys this error "python dev has no installation candidate is sucking my precious time  I read a book and it had mitmf now that tool isn't even installing , I wasted time over it can someone help?

I m very new to linux and very beginner to programming , everything was going well but this rubbish python error killed me . Help plz I tried everything available on every help forum.

Comment: `python dev` definitly has no install candidate. Did you mean `python-dev`? What command leads up to this error? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/708422/edit) your question to include this information.

Comment: Along with what @Panki asked for, please add your distro name/version to your question.